# Is it rude to ask for toilet paper in Bangladesh?

Tags: local-customs, hygiene, bangladesh

I have read this post : [Stuck without toilet paper while travelling - what is the best approach?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/stuck-without-toilet-paper-while-travelling-what-is-the-best-approach) Does not quite answer my question.

Are toilet papers common in hotels in Dhaka ? It seems too off to mail the hotel asking for this. Even before I can mail I need to know if whether it is rude/offensive to ask for toilet paper in Dhaka/Bangladesh (to the hotel staff/grocery stores)? Even if I had to buy one for myself, are they readily available in grocery stores/marts ?

Comment: If you can not ask directly toilet paper then ask for tissue paper.
In general, Bangladeshi use tissue paper instead of toilet paper ...

Comment: @HaLaBi The concierge desk sent me a list to pick from. Although am more inclined towards extended stay hotels, I am picking whoever's got them toilet papers. Do the number of stars of a hotel provide a lead of toilet paper availability ?

Comment: I asked because 5 stars hotels always provide anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have been to Dhaka many, many times. In these times I stayed in two different hotels, they both had toilet paper just like any other hotel in the world.

A quick google image search using the query [(hotel in Dhaka toilet)](https://www.google.com/search?q=sonargaon+hotel+in+dhaka+toilet&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-US%3aIE-Address&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9UnvUdbVLcWjPfS_geAE&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1670&bih=788#safe=active&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-US%3AIE-Address&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=hotel+in+dhaka+toilet&oq=hotel+in+dhaka+toilet&gs_l=img.12...144705.144705.0.145487.1.1.0.0.0.0.363.363.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.22.img..1.0.0.0AwlMZq_0iE&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49641647,d.ZWU&fp=222b40cb29c20d1d&biw=1670&bih=788&imgdii=_) revealed a lot of toilet photos for hotel toilets there, all of them seem to show toilet paper. Also, reading Dhaka hotel reviews in TripAvidor showed no such issue. Finally, you are free to ask for the toilet paper because most people who live in countries where they use water instead of toilet paper they also use toilet paper to dry after using the water. So no worries.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Nothing beats personal experience.

Answer (score 13):

Really, there's no need to mail them about it. Just deal with it when you get there - it may not even be a problem.

Then, when you get there, IF there is none, ask the staff.  Either it's missing and they forgot to put some there, and they'll refill it.  Or, they'll be used to non-Bangladeshis asking about this, and will offer you some suggestions.  Even if they find it a bit odd to ask, they work in tourism and realise that people are different and may not be used to their ways.  Be polite and semi-apologetic about it, and it's pretty hard to offend.

And if the grocery store sells it, then under no circumstance would it be rude to ask them for some.

However, another suggestion is to embrace the local customs, and do what they do.  Often there'll be a supply of water - a container or tap.  Take some, use that to wipe with, and then wash your hands afterwards.  It works for millions of people, and [some argue that it's even better than toilet paper](http://www.sciencetoymaker.org/bangladesh/toiletHygene.htm).

Odds are if they have a western-style toilet, they'll have paper.  If, however, it's a squat toilet, [we have a useful page on how to use those](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3080/101), if you're interested.

Answer (score 6):

#### You'll get

As a Muslim Country like others, Bangladeshi people are used to using toilet paper (gender independent) for two reasons:

- To become purified as Islam said about using water/solid-soil after toilet, and instead of solid-soil in urban areas people use toilet papers
- To show high standard - especially in rural areas, people use toilet paper or at least put one in their toilet to show that they are living high standard as other urban dwellers.

And in hotels, it's about mandatory to put Toilet paper in their toilet to serve their customer with a high standard.

#### You won't

But there's an exception only, and is the Public toilets. You won't get any toilet paper in Public toilets, because:

- Not all of them are well maintained, or
- They don't think it's necessary to decorate a Public toilet with toilet paper-like less important(!) material

#### Not to worry... :)

But for any foreigner to Bangladesh, you'll be served with their best, and they know you'll need a toilet paper. So you'll be well-equiped in toilet, but in case, just don't hesitate, and ask for one. They'd love to serve you with one, or buy one for you. :)

Happy travelling!

Comment: I have traveled to other Muslim countries (Indonesia, Malaysia) and I rarely found toilet paper in any toilets, so I find it a little bit hard to believe that Muslim countries generally use toilet paper.

Comment: @drat But I's actually talking about the Bangladeshi values in modern times. They are taking toilet papers into their everyday life most because of the theo support. :) Anyways thanks for the info though, I's unaware about such conditions in other Muslim countries.